# I tried to create a Web service on Render using a Flowise Github repository but the deploy failed

Tags: node.js, github, render, flowise

Please see screenshot of the error log from Render.

The Flowise Github repository was to deploy on Render but the deploy failed and the code needs some debugging.

Below are the details of the error code also available in the screenshot.

flowise-components:build: nodes/tools/CustomTool/core.ts(103,21): error TS2416: Property '_call' in type 'DynamicStructuredTool' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'StructuredTool<ZodObject<any, any, any, any, { [x: string]: any; }>>'.

[screenshot of the error log from Render. enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGXWQ.png)